# Can class member arrays / std::arrays be replaced?

Tags: c++, arrays

New to C++, looking to replicate some functionality available in C# involving replacing an object array member with a newly constructed array.

```
class Car {
    int id;
    Car() {}
};
class Garage {
    Car cars[1];
    Garage() {}
    void addCars(Car crs[]) {
        //...do update here
    }
};
```

In C# I could do something like:

```
addCars(Car[] crs){
    Car[] temp = new Car[cars.Length + crs.Length];
    for(int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++){
        temp[i] = cars[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < crs.Length; i++){
        temp[i + cars.Length] = crs[i];
    }
    cars = temp;
}
```

Or `Array.Resize`, `Array.Copy`.

Can I declare an array and replace an existing object instance member array?

If this isn't possible: How practical are arrays in C++? I can see something like Excel utilising them (if they aren't modifiable) but it seems like it would be really limited. I can see why memory allocation might constrain this but obviously I'm from the easier side of the C fence.

Thanks.

Comment: What you're doing in C# is reinventing `List<Car>`. C++ has `std::vector`.

Comment: @chris: I use similar where the array rarely changes in size or if I need to read into a List (say parsing a file) when working with a lot of entries. Performance varies in C# comparing arrays to lists so I use arrays when it's not overkill.

Comment: @CBusBus: You'll find that `std::vector` has very little performance overhead. Use them and never look back.

Comment: @CBusBus You can set the internal capacity of C#'s `List`, to avoid unnecessary reallocations, either via constructor, or by setting the `Capacity` property. You can do the same with `std::vector`, and `reserve` method.

Comment: @AndyG Thanks for the tip, seems to be the general consensus. I'll worry about array management in the future if I really need it.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius. Thanks for the heads up. I use arrays in C# mostly for read performance. It's hit or miss but performance can be 50% better in some cases.

Comment: @CBusBus 1) In my personal experience, other things, such as algorithm choice, impacts the overall performance way more, than the innate performance hit of Lists vs Arrays. 2) If you know the initial capacity in advance, and set it correctly via the constructor of `List`, to avoid reallocations, I wouldn't expect the difference to be measurable.

Comment: And the tests that I did seem to confirm that (Given the class you show in your example, it took more than 10 million elements in list/array), for the insertion to be measurable (> 1 second), and even then, the container, for which insertion was faster, depended on the run. I am curious as to how you measured it, where you got 50% difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I declare an array and replace an existing object instance member array?

No, `std::array` and `type[]` array sizes are known at compile time. If the new array has the same size as the existing array, a copy is needed (via e.g., `memcpy`)

You could theoretically use a pointer instead, e.g.

```
Car cars* = nullptr;
// ...
cars = new Car[size];
// ...
delete[] cars;
```

However, this puts the burden of memory tracking on you (I had to manually call `delete[]`). Instead, use a `std::vector`, which wraps up all that logic for you.

```
std::vector<Car> cars;
Car c;
// ...
cars.push_back(c);
```

> How practical are arrays in C++?

Quite practical. A lot of high performance computing relies on arrays whose sizes are known at compile time for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

As an example, here would be some sort of C++ equivalent to your example.  It probably has some vague semblance to the C# equivalent.

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ostream;
using std::initializer_list;

struct Car {
  int id;
  Car(int newId) : id{newId} {}
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, Car const& car) {
  o << car.id;
  return o;
}

struct Garage {
  vector<Car> cars;
  Garage() {}

  void addCars(initializer_list<Car> l) {
    cars.insert(cars.end(), l.begin(), l.end());
  }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, Garage const& garage) {
  char const* sep = "";
  for (auto const& car : garage.cars) {
    o << sep << car;
    sep = ", ";
  }
  return o;
}

int main() {
  Garage garage;
  garage.addCars({7, 8, 99, 1000});
  cout << garage << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Prepared almost identical answer but you ninjaed me. upvoted

Answer (score 0):

The C++ arrays and [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) are fixed size at compile time. Their size can't change at runtime.  You can copy an `std::array` onto another `std::array` ("replace").  But you can't do so for the C++ build-in arrays: these need to be copied element by element for example with [`std::copy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

If you need to dynamically resize your container, you should consider [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.  These are much more flexible.  And you can of course copy or move them as a whole.